# Replace text string with jQuery on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code in my html

```
<p>6565655655|cell</p>
```

I want to remove this vertical line and wrap word "cell" into round bracket. So I want output like below

```
<p>6565655655 (cell)</p>
```

How I can do it using jquery when content of p tag loading dynamically by ajax call.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the content of the p-tag with the pipe as delimiter and re-insert the so created array, second element with surrounding bracket.

Here an example:

```
var splittedString = $("p").text().split("|");
$("p").html(splittedString[0] + " (" + splittedString[1] + ")");
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r3c4J/

Answer (score 0):

Few ways to do it:

```
var text = '6565655655|cell';
```

Method 1:

```
var parts = text.split('|');
$('p').text(parts[0] + ' (' + parts[1] + ')');
```

Method 2:

```
$('p').text(text.replace('|cell', ' (cell)');
```

Method 3:

```
$('p').text(text.replace(/([0-9]+)\|(.*)/, '$1 ($2)'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$('p').each(function () {
    var $txt = $(this).text();

    if ($txt.indexOf('|') > 0) {
        var txtArray = $txt.split('|');
        $(this).html(txtArray[0] + ' (' + txtArray[1] + ')');
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fewds/E637y/1/

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax success method:

```
success: function(data)
{
 $(data).find("p").each(function(index,element){
  var pipe = element.innerHTML.indexOf("|");
  if( pipe != -1 ){
   element.innerHTML.replace("|","( ");
   element.innerHTML += ")";
  }
 }
 //continue with placing data on the page.
}
```

you could also farm this out into a function so you could call it when the page first loads too

```
function replacePipe(element)
{
  $(element).find("p").each(function(index,el){
  var pipe = el.innerHTML.indexOf("|");
  if( pipe != -1 ){
   el.innerHTML.replace("|","( ");
   el.innerHTML += ")";
  }
 }
}
```

which would make the ajax success look like this:

```
success: function(data)
{
 replacePipe(data);
 //place data, perhaps $(tar).html(data);
}
```

and you could do this onload too

```
window.onload = function(){ 
 replacePipe(document.body);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class name to the paragraph tag then you could also use the following...

html part -

```
<p class="item">6565655655|cell</p>
```

jQuery part

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var aText = ($('.item').html()).split('|');
$('.item').html(aText[0] + "&nbsp;&#40;" + aText[1] + "&#41;");
});
```